# Custom Field that is a Foreign key to contact in Custom Group that extends Event is not updated on merge of contacts

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I have created a Custom Group for Events. This Group has one custom field Organizor which is a autocomplete with contacts.
But on merging the contact the Organizor custom field is not updated accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This is something not handle in CiviCRM at the moment when two contacts are merged. I am not sure if any one has submitted fix for this issue. You can either fix this by adding code  to update contact_id for all contact reference custom field in core or through [hook_civicrm_merge](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_merge/) hook via extension.

HTH

Pradeep